# SFDX - Pull command doesn't recognize metadata coming from package install

Tags: salesforcedx

Well, the question is fairly straight forward -  I installed an unmanaged package in the org via the url it provides and when I went to the console and tried to pull the changes with the `sfdx force:source:pull -u myScratch` it keeps saying `No results found`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it a know issue or something?

Just to illustrate, here are some images -

[image: IDE]

[image: Salesforce]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pull the package using sfdx command directly to your source instead of installing it via URL and pulling later. Use:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r [Target Folder] -p [Package Name] -u [Source Org Name] -w 10
```

Then convert the downloaded metadata to DX project format using:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r [Target Folder]
```

Hope this helps.